# Package reference in C# has the wrong using statements

Tags: c#, nuget, azure-artifacts, packagereference

I have a C# project in VS Code running on .NET 6.0. I have a package reference which is the correct version, but the using statements in it are from an older version which causes errors, and I have no idea how to fix it.

If I reference it from a project reference, it works.

When I click <kbd>F12</kbd> to view the file, I can see the differences, but also see the package is the right one (earlier it was referencing an older version which caused the same problem).

I have run `dotnet clean`, `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` but the issue persists.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the using statements in it"? A package reference has no using statements. And: which errors do you get?

Comment: I don't get the what package reference has todo with the namespaces in the assemblies found in the installed package? You need to be more clear.

Comment: i reference the package in the csproj file, and in the cs file i use a class from the package, when i click f12 to view the class, at the top it shows the information and the package ie what version it is, which is correct, but it also shows the using states within the class and 1 of them is wrong. I hope that explains it more, never had this before

Comment: Delete the using statement if it no longer is needed.

Comment: its in dll from a package reference, its been changed but the new version is appearing to have an old using reference in it

Comment: however i think i have found it, couldn't find how do to this before but i have cleared all my nuget cache and it seems to have fixed it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up clearing the nuget cache using cli as visual studio code as no internal mechanism.

n the dotnet CLI, use dotnet nuget locals all --clear.
In the NuGet CLI, use nuget locals all -clear.